# Reusing highchart chart many times on the same page by changing parse string

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, highcharts

I have been struggling with this for a few days now. I was trying to find ways to do this, I thought of changing code so it had a "wrapping" function and took the string to parse as input so it would be changeable. So for example.

```
var call = function(year)
  ($.get('Veidilands.csv', function(data) {
            // Split the lines
            var lines = data.split('\n');

            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(';');

              //Declare the year, search for entries only for that year
                var STRINGTOPARSEWITH = line.indexOf(year);    


                // header line containes categories
                if (lineNo == 0) {
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo > 1) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);

                    });
                }

                // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
                else if(lineNo != 0 && STRINGTOPARSEWITH == 0  )  {
```

Would Change into

```
($.get('Veidilands.csv', function(data) {
            // Split the lines
            var lines = data.split('\n');

            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(';');

                var STRINGTOPARSEWITH = line.indexOf('2000');    




                // header line containes categories
                if (lineNo == 0) {
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo > 1) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);

                    });
                }

                // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
                else if(lineNo != 0 && STRINGTOPARSEWITH == 0
```

In addition to that how would I go about implementing that into the html file. I have now many charts that output to the same container but all with just this tiny difference in the year and I am reusing a lot of code that I think I can make better use of. Would it be better to have some sort of function that simply changes the year string on click. What is the best way to handle this and how can I do it. Thank you very much in advance.

Here is a link to my code  http://jsfiddle.net/9Anu8/  As you can see it becomes very bulky and inefficient to reuse so much code. I would very much appreciate any tips you could offer.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call this an instance of "reusing" code. I would call this "copy/paste" of code :) Yes this approach doesn't scale well. You must try to distill what is common in all cases. When you have done that you can create a new function (e.g. display_chart) that takes as parameters those parts that need to change. For example, it seems that the options object is almost always the same. What changes is the text for the title. Also, I notice that your click handlers start like this $( "#id" ).click(function() { $(function () {.  You don't need the "$(function () {" inside there.

Comment: for example a first stab at simplifying this would be to have function that returns a configuration object, e.g. function get_chart_options(title) { var options = //option code here return options;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok just to follow up on my comments. (this is stricly not a complete answer but point in the right directions). You could for example have function like this:

```
function display_chart_options(main_title,yaxis_title) {
    return {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
            /*type: ''*/
        },
        title: {
            text: main_title
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: yaxis_title
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        legend: {

            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 15,
            borderWidth: 0,
            itemStyle: {

               color: '#333',
               fontSize: '15px',

            },
            navigation: {
            activeColor: '#3E576F',
            animation: true,
            arrowSize: 12,
            inactiveColor: '#CCC',

            style: {
               fontWeight: 'bold',
               color: '#333',
               fontSize: '15px',

            }
         }
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {

                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },
        series: []

    };
}
```

and then in your click handlers:

```
$( "#klikk1" ).click(function() {
    var options = display_chart_options('Veiði','Fjöldi');
    $.get('prof4.csv', function(data) {
        // Split the lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split(';');


            // header line containes categories
            if (lineNo == 0) {
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);

                });
            }

            // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
            else if(lineNo != 0 && items != null )  {
                var series = { 
                    data: [],
                    visible:false,
                   /* type: 'line'*/

                }
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo == 0) {
                        series.name = item;     
                    }
                    else if(itemNo !=0)  {
                        series.data.push({
                            y: parseFloat(item),

                        });
                    }


                });


                options.series.push(series);

            }

        });

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```